# How to select all using "__in" in drf on empty list?

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-queryset, drf-queryset

For example, if i had to select specific ids I can do this using:
`id_list=[1,4,7]`

```py
Blog.objects.filter(pk__in=id_list)
```

But the problem is `id_list` is being populated using filters selected in front end.
so initially `id_list` will be empty(`id_list=[]`)

so, is there a way to select all the ids using `Blog.objects.filter(pk__in=id_list)` when `id_list` is empty?

Comment: You can simply do the `if and else` to return queryset with respect to the given value of `id_list`.

Comment: @dipesh There can be multiple filters, so if-else won't be a correct approach.

Comment: @ShubhamKumar You only need to handle the case where the list is empty differently. The multiple filters would be contained in `id_list` if there are filters. How is that not a correct approach?

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
if len(id_list) == 0:
     queryset = Blog.objects.all()
else:
     queryset = Blog.objects.filter(pk__in=id_list)
```